# Datatables change language dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to change with jQuery language of a table with datatables. I'm trying to push a button to change the language of the table.

```
$('#prueba').live('click', function () {
var espanol = {
     "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
     "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
     "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
     "sInfo": "Mostrando desde _START_ hasta _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
     "sInfoEmpty": "No existen registros",
     "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ líneas)",
     "sInfoPostFix": "",
     "sSearch": "Buscar:",
     "sUrl": "",
"oPaginate": {
"sFirst":    "Primero",
"sPrevious": "Anterior",
"sNext":     "Siguiente",
"sLast":     "Último"
}
};
tablacliente.fnSettings().oLanguage= espanol;
tablacliente.fnDraw();
})
```

Comment: And, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no built-in method or plug-in (currently) to switch the language dynamically. But what you can do is destroy the datatable and re-initialize it with the new language setting.

So, change your button's click handler to something like this:

```
$('#prueba').click(function(){
    if (typeof tablacliente != 'undefined' && tablacliente != null)
    {
        tablacliente.fnDestroy(); //important! you have to destroy first or you'll get an alert-error.
        tablacliente = null;
        tablacliente = $('#table_id').dataTable( {"oLanguage": espanol} ); //don't forget to include any other settings, if you have.
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpuWD/).

Comment: Uh, there is no other option? that's terrible in performance. Imagine I have 6 tables full of data and I need to regenerate everything just to change some labels... T_T

Answer (score 2):

As the original poster mentioned, this does not work:

```
tablacliente.fnSettings().oLanguage = espanol;    // does not work!
```

but something like this should work, without having to destroy the table:

```
var oLanguage = tablacliente.fnSettings().oLanguage;
for (var field in espanol) {
    oLanguage[field] = espanol[field];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$countries = array (
    "tr-TR"=>"//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Turkish.json",
    "de-DE" =>"//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/German.json",
    "es-ES"=>"//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
);
?>
<script>
    var locale='<?php echo $countries[locale_get_default()];?>';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#page-params').dataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": locale
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is not correct because it doesn't explain how to change the language dynamically.

Comment: I am not a php developer but now ı am writing a freelance php project this worked on my system

Comment: you must do something like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

tablacliente.fnSettings().oLanguage= espanol;
tablacliente.fnUpdate();

Works for me.