# Switch datatables table language with using polylang plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datatable

I'm playing around with the [polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin in `wordpress` and I have to say that it does good job for me. However, I have one issue I want to solve.

In my website I also use [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin, which allows to represent my posts in a table with some sorting. It has some language files and I can change the language statically. However, what I want to do is to change it dynamically, when I switch the language with polylang.

I found the partial solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370715/datatables-change-language-dynamically). It allows to change the language of the table by pressing the special dedicated button. I was wondering maybe it's possible to hook that button click function to the button of the language switcher?

I use the function

```
 pll_the_languages(array('show_flags'=>1,'show_names'=>0));
```

in my code to show the language switcher.

Thanks for any effort.

Any help would highly appreciated